# Installing a Vim package. syntax highlighting does not turn on

Tags: syntax-highlighting, installing

I want to use the [nuweb.vim](https://github.com/vim-scripts/nuweb.vim/blob/master/syntax/nuweb.vim) extension for syntax highlighting [nuweb files](http://nuweb.sourceforge.net/nuwebdoc.pdf).

Long story short, nuweb files are basically a super-set of latex files. There is added syntax and markers to embed code-snippets in Latex so that one can do literate programming in the style of Knuth.

However, I have not been able to get the nuweb.vim file to get to work 
for nuweb files. (These typically have extensions .nw)

Here a sample nuweb file, titled `fun.nw`

```
$\alpha + \beta=\gamma$

@o output.cpp
@{# /* C++*/
#include<iostream>
int main(void){
  std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}

@}
```

My .vimrc file looks like this

```
colorscheme torte
set guifont=Inconsolata\ 14
set laststatus=2

filetype on
filetype plugin on

set runtimepath^=/home/smilingbuddha/.vim/bundle/nuweb.vim
```

On opening the nuweb files, I don't get the necessary syntax highlightin. Doing `:set syntax?` I get output `syntax=conf` in the mode-line at the bottom.

Where am I going wrong? I am not used to Vim so I am pretty much a newbie.

Comment: put the syntax\nuweb.vim inside `~/.vim/syntax`. If Vim already detects nuweb files, it should just work, else you would need an additional rule to detect a new filetype (see `:h new-filetype`)

Comment: Check `:set ft?`

Answer (score 1):

The [vimscripts entry](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=543) for nuweb.vim (which is referred to by the README.md in the GitHub repository) gets into more details about how to install it:

> **install details**
> As WEB/CWEB uses *.w, i recoment use *.nw for NUWEB, so some like
> `au BufNewFile,BufRead *.nw      setf nuweb`
> in filetype.vim will do the trick.

In modern Vim, this is typically accomplished by an `ftdetect` plug-in, so you should probably include a `~/.vim/ftdetect/nuweb.vim` with exactly those contents listed above. Create that file with this single line in it:

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.nw setf nuweb
```

Perhaps it would make sense to suggest including this `ftdetect/nuweb.vim` with the GitHub repository for it. But given the GitHub repository hasn't been touched in 10 years and the vimscripts page for the plug-in is actually even older, from 2003, I don't know whether you'll have luck in getting any of the maintainers to incorporate that suggestion...

Answer (score 0):

Simply put `syntax on` on your vimrc